# How do I set the connection timeout for my AdomdConnection?

Tags: c#, connection, connection-string, adomd.net

I've read thoroughly about AdomdConnection but can't find how to set the Connection Timeout in my connection string.
My current connection string is as follows:

```
Data Source=MySSAS;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog
```

But no matter what I do, any variation of `Connection Timeout`, `ConnectionTimeout`, `Connect Timeout` or `ConnectTimeout` doesn't seem to change my connection ([MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdconnection.connectionstring.aspx)

I observe the connection properties in my debugger and always see the getter value of the `ConnectionTimeout` as 0:

[image]

Needles to say that the property has no setter.

Does anyone know how to set it? I'm only interested in the connection timeout, not command timeout.

Comment: As you mention, there is no setter, so you cant set it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx - also why are you trying to set the time to wait for a connection, doesn't it connect immediately?

Comment: @Michael - Sometime my server is down and this causes clients to hang for a long time. In most cases (that I'm aware of) connections don't have a setter for the timeout but when the connection string has this property it does set the timeout accordingly.Unfortunately, this is not the case with Adomd connection

Comment: I think you meant to ping @Jeremy, not me. Pinging him myself now.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the correction Michael

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer over at [MSDN - SSAS Client Connection Timeout](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/6127a95e-fe12-4781-bee1-296651468baa/):

In msmdsrv.ini:
<InitialConnectTimeout>10</InitialConnectTimeout>

Perhaps you can verify what SQL does by running a trace when you connect:

[image]

*Or it maybe even though you are seeing `Connection Timeout = 0` in Visual Studio on the client the value on the server could be different.*

Also dont forget you could resort to pinging the server for a minute as an alternative to the Connection Timeout setting.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't see anything in SSMS tracing, although I found it strange that the default there is 15 seconds whereas it's 0 (i.e. unlimited) for AdomdConnection. I guess I can believe that the actual Connection timeout is set although it's not being shown as such in the VS. I'll give it a try

Comment: If I am making an ADOMD connection, setting timeout in SQL server management studio will not help.